# what is the name of this data structure

Tags: data-structures

```
   (10)
   /  \
 (9)  (8)
 /  \ /  \
(7) (5) (4) 

x        x
/   and  \    == x=>y
y         y
```

Comment: What does `x=>y` mean? *x* ≥ *y*? *x* ⇒ *y*? (*x*, *y*) ∈ *E* (*G*)

Comment: are you sure (5) is supposed to have two parents?

Comment: @Malfist sure why not, that just means it's not a tree.

Comment: x≥y
yea (5) is suppose to be there. Maybe my instructor made this structure up randomly, I was curious what the name would be, thanks

Comment: It's not a tree, since in a tree each element has exactly one parent (except for the root).

Comment: @Shell: the question is not whether (5) is supposed to be *there* but whether it’s supposed to have two parents! If yes, then the data structure doesn’t make much sense in the light of your revelation that `x=>y` means x≥y.

Comment: yea its suppose to have two parents, which are both bigger than the child (5). Basically all parents are bigger or equal to their children.
But again I guess my instructor made this up himself, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG), which can define a (partial) ordering relation.

Comment: well , if (5) is a child of (9) and (8), then it is cyclic. But that might have been a typo by the OP... not sure.

Comment: @Fru: From his `x=>y` comment I understand that he means a *directed* graph, with all edges running down. You don't have a cycle that way, since once you reach (5) you cannot go up again.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: He seems to have defined a direction (x=>y), so it's not cyclic.

Comment: Actually, I see nothing to indicate direction, either.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I thought he mean to type `>=` instead of `=>` so I did not interpret it the same way.
If that's how he meant it then yes, DAG is correct.

Comment: I think we can all agree that as it currently is, there's multiple contradicting intepretations...

Comment: sorry everyone, I was just curious if this structure actually existed, but maybe my instructor made this up himself

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a max-[heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), except that (5) should not be attached to two parents.

A max-heap is a tree-based data structure where `x>=y` if x is a parent of y. Since it is a tree, each child can only have one parent.

Comment: What's this "should not" business? As shown, it's a perfectly valid structure. It may just not be a max-heap.

Comment: I meant that if it is a max-heap then a child should not be attached to two parents. I still think that the instructor had meant a heap.